# A counter example and a resolution for the same question. Which is false?

Tags: analysis

Q. Let $f :\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a continuous function, if $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded then it is $F(X)$.

A. If $X$ is bounded then exists $\delta$ such that $X \subset B[0;\delta]$. If $f$ is continuous then $f(B[0;\delta])$ is compact and then $f(X)$ because $F(X) \subset f(B[0;\delta])$.

Counter-example. $f :\mathbb{R}-{0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}-{0}$, $f(x) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{x}$. f is continuous, X = (0,1] is bounded but $f(X)$ is not.

Comment: $f$ is not defined on $R$ for the counterexample

Comment: In the question, the domain of $f$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is important, as illustrated by the example.